# How to automate or create a scheduled Job for the below query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, automation, scheduled-tasks

I am having the following query to check whether any data is stored in SQL Cache

```
select er.*, st.*
from sys.dm_exec_requests er
cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(er.sql_handle) st
where st.text not like '%C7DB%' -- filter self
GO
```

From the above query I need to pick the `Plan_Handle`(if any present) and run the 2nd query to clear the SQL Cache

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE (0x060007002D2BE10840E13F38030000000000000000000000);
```

I need to run this manually every 30 mins.

Can you please suggest, how to automate this process

Answer (score 1):

- In java, we can automate this, by using Quartz Time scheduler.
- You have to write one simple java program, deploy it on the server, and it automatically runs(Which executes your sql statements and done your task) after a particular time.
- Follow this link, you will get your task done within 1-2 hours.
- Link - "http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/"

Answer (score 0):

Simple Java Program :-
i. Write a HelloSchedule class which have configuration about your repetition information like every 30 mins. (It need quartz jar file, you can download it from quartz webside)

```
import java.util.Date;

import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SchedulerFactory;
import org.quartz.SimpleTrigger;
import org.quartz.impl.JobDetailImpl;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;
import org.quartz.impl.triggers.SimpleTriggerImpl;

public class HelloSchedule {

    public HelloSchedule() throws Exception {
        SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        Scheduler sched = sf.getScheduler();
        sched.start();
        JobDetailImpl jd = new JobDetailImpl("myjob", sched.DEFAULT_GROUP, HelloJob.class);
        SimpleTriggerImpl st = new SimpleTriggerImpl("mytrigger", sched.DEFAULT_GROUP, new Date(),
                null, SimpleTrigger.REPEAT_INDEFINITELY, 60L * 1000L);
        //60L * 1000L - It is time for it is repeting, after each 1 min it is executing.You have to replace here for half hour.
        sched.scheduleJob(jd, st);
    }

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Before Cron execution complition...!!!");
        new HelloSchedule();
        System.out.println("After Cron execution complition...!!!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

}
```

ii. Write a HelloJob class.

```
public class HelloJob implements Job {

public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException{

   // Write here your Repetation behaviour.
   // That is Connectivity with your database. 
   // Your Sql1 and Sql2
}
}
```